# React Native Breadcrumb

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-native-navigation, breadcrumbs

I am making a React Native application in which I have menus and submenus.

**Menus and submenus structure:**

```
let arr = [
  {
    name: 'Header 1',
    routeName: 'Home',
    child: [
      { name: 'Header 1 - Submenu 1', child: [], routeName: 'Home' },
      {
        name: 'Header 1 - Submenu 2',
        child: [],
        routeName: 'NotificationScreen',
      },
      { name: 'Header 1 - Submenu 3', child: [], routeName: 'Home' },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Header 2',
    routeName: 'NotificationScreen',
    child: [
      {
        name: 'Header 2 - Submenu 1',
        child: [],
        routeName: 'NotificationScreen',
      },
      { name: 'Header 2 - Submenu 2', child: [], routeName: 'Home' },
      {
        name: 'Header 2 - Submenu 3',
        child: [],
        routeName: 'NotificationScreen',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

**Render of Menu's and Submenu's:**

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={onPress} activeOpacity={1}>
  <View style={styles.row}>
    <Text style={{ paddingRight: 20 }}>{name}</Text>
    {child.length ? <Text>{open ? 'close' : 'open'}</Text> : null}
  </View>
  {open &&
    child.map((x: any, i: any) => {
      if (x.child.length) {
        return (
          <Item
            key={x}
            active={childActive}
            i={i}
            setActive={setChildActive}
            child={x.child}
          />
        );
      }
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          key={x}
          style={styles.subItem}
          onPress={() => {
            handleRouteChange(x.routeName);
          }}>
          <Text>
            {name} - submenu - {i + 1}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    })}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

> **Working example:** https://snack.expo.dev/@manirajmurugan/custom-header-title-component

Here I am in the need to make a breadcrumb like structure on the screen page as per the navigation done by user through menu and submenus.

**Current Scenario:**

-> If user clicks on Header 1 and then select submenu Header 1 - Submenu 1, then the user will be redirected to Home Screen.

**Expected Scenario:**

-> Requirement here is that I am in the need to display a breadcrumb for this screen like,

```
Header 1 > Header 1 - Submenu 1
```

On click of the Header 1 in this breadcrumb, user will be redirected to the respective `routeName` given in the object.

Kindly help me to generate breadcrumb for the navigation done in menu for the respective screen's.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

In real app menu and submenu will be like,

[image]

Here if user click's on `Stored Data configuration` under `Unit Data Management`,

then the expected breadcrumb result would be,

[image]

Comment: I think a SectionList will get you the layout you are looking for. I started to flesh something out here https://snack.expo.dev/stOpFq7vJ

Comment: @PhantomSpooks, Thanks bro for your edit. Here if you look both first and second image, then it can be noted that based on the selection from the menu and submenu, the breadcrumb is made in the respective screen top left (As like given in second image).

Comment: Consider the user is selecting `Unit Data Management` -> `Stored Data Configuration` then in the breadcrumb of the page will look like `Home > Unit Data Management: Stored Data Configuration`

Comment: @PhantomSpooks, Once again thanks for your effort bro. Kindly help me to achieve the result of displaying the breadcrumb like given in the second image dynamically based on the menu and submenu selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a piece of state to hold the crumbs. It will be an array that will hold three values: the screen you are currently on, the section title press, and the section item pressed. Handling the last two will be done by the SectionList and to keep track of the current screen you can add a [screenListener](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/#screenlisteners-prop-on-the-navigator) to the StackNavigator that will listen for all navigation changes on all screens.

```js
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Header from './screens/Header';
import HomeScreen from './screens/Home';
import SettingsScreen from './screens/Settings';
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

import { ICON_SIZE, headerHeight } from './Constants';
const initialScreen = 'Settings';

export default function App() {
  // this will have at most 3 items:
  //   the current screen
  //   the section header
  //   the section.data[index]
  const [crumbNavigation, setCrumbNavigation] = useState([initialScreen]);
  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();
  const screenOptions = {
    // pass crumbNavigation and its setter to header
    headerTitle: (props) => (
      <Header
        {...props}
        width={width}
        height={headerHeight}
        crumbNavigation={crumbNavigation}
        setCrumbNavigation={setCrumbNavigation}
      />
    ),
    headerStyle: {
      height: headerHeight,
      width: width,
    },
    // since there will be a bread crumb navigator
    // theres no need for back button
    headerBackVisible: false,
    headerLeft: () => null,
  };
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName={initialScreen}
        screenOptions={screenOptions}
        screenListeners={{
          state: (nav) => {
            console.log(nav.type);
            const routes = nav.data.state.routes;
            const lastRoute = routes[routes.length - 1]?.name;
            if (lastRoute)
              setCrumbNavigation((prev) => {
                prev[0] = lastRoute;
                return prev;
              });
          },
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Now that current screen is handled, you can move on to deal with getting the SectionTitle, which the SectionHeader and MenuItem components handles. If a section data array's length is zero, pressing it will trigger the parent component's onItemPress with the section as an argument, if not, then pressing it will reveal its children

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import TouchableMaterialIcon from './TouchableMaterialIcon';
import { ICON_SIZE } from '../Constants';
export default function SectionHeader({ section, toggleSectionMenu, onPress }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={[
        styles.headerContainer,
        section.isOpen && styles.highlightedTitleContainer,
      ]}
      onPress={()=>{
        if(section.data.length > 0)
          toggleSectionMenu(section.id)
        else
          onPress(section.title)
      }}
      >
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text
          styles={[
            styles.titleText,
            section.isOpen && styles.highlightedTitleText,
          ]}>
          {section.title}
        </Text>
      </View>
      {section.data.length > 0 && (
        <TouchableMaterialIcon
          name={section.isOpen ? 'keyboard-arrow-up' : 'keyboard-arrow-down'}
          size={ICON_SIZE * 0.6}
          onPress={() => toggleSectionMenu(section.id)}
        />
      )}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  headerContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    // justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    borderBottomColor: '#eee',
    paddingVertical: 5,
  },
  titleText: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  highlightedTitleText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  highlightedTitleContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#edf',
  },
});
```

The SectionItem is pretty straightforward. When visible, its a button that when pressed will trigger its grandparent's onItemPressed with both the section title and the item's title

```js
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function MenuItem({ section, index, item, onPress }) {
  const isLastItem = index == section.data.length - 1;
  if (section.isOpen)
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[styles.itemContainer, isLastItem && styles.lastItem]}
        onPress={() => onPress(section.title, item)}>
        <Text>{item}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  itemContainer: {
    marginRight: 5,
    padding: 5,
  },
  lastItem: {
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    borderBottomColor: '#eee',
  },
});
```

ButtonWithMenu contains a button that when pressed, renders the SectionList directly beneath it. It accepts an onItemPress prop which will be passed on into the SectionList:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  SectionList,
  useWindowDimensions,
  Modal,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from 'react-native';

import TouchableMaterialIcon from './TouchableMaterialIcon';
import MenuItem from './MenuItem';
import SectionHeader from './SectionHeader';
import useLayout from '../hooks/useLayout';

export default function DropDownButtonMenu({
  name,
  size,
  color,
  onItemPress,
  buttonStyle,
  containerStyle,
  menu,
  onMenuAction,
}) {
  const [openMenu, setOpenMenu] = useState(false);
  const [buttonLayout, onButtonLayout] = useLayout();
  // add additional state to menu
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState(
    menu?.map((section, i) => {
      section.isOpened = false;
      section.id = `section-item-${i}`;
      return section;
    }) || []
  );
  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();
  const handleButtonPress = () => {
    setOpenMenu((prev) => !prev);
  };
  const toggleSectionMenu = (sectionId) => {    
    // deep clone menuItems
    const newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(menuItems));
    const index = newData.findIndex((section) => section.id == sectionId);
    if (index < 0) {
      console.log('Section id not found');
      return;
    }
    newData[index].isOpen = !newData[index].isOpen;
    setMenuItems(newData);
  };
  const handleItemPress = (sectionTitle,itemTitle)=>{
    onItemPress(sectionTitle,itemTitle)
    setOpenMenu(false)
  }
  return (
    <View style={[containerStyle, { zIndex: 1 }]}>
      <TouchableMaterialIcon
        style={buttonStyle}
        name={name}
        size={size}
        color={color}
        onLayout={onButtonLayout}
        onPress={handleButtonPress}
        disabled={menuItems.length < 1}
      />
      {/* 
      wrap modal in touchable so that pressing outside modal will close it
      tried to use absolute positioned view but no matter the zIndex but
      the screen contents would always appear on top
      */}
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setOpenMenu(false)}>
        <Modal transparent visible={openMenu}>
          <View
            style={[
              styles.menu,
              {
                top: buttonLayout.y + buttonLayout.height,
                left: buttonLayout.left,
                minWidth: 150,
                maxHeight: height * 0.6,
              },
            ]}>
            <SectionList
              sections={menuItems}
              renderItem={(props) => <MenuItem {...props} onPress={handleItemPress} />}
              renderSectionHeader={(props) => (
                <SectionHeader
                  {...props}
                  toggleSectionMenu={toggleSectionMenu}
                  onPress={handleItemPress}
                />
              )}
            />
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  menu: {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 10,
    zIndex: 10,
  },
});
```

Now in the Header component the only thing that is left to do is create a list for the SectionList to render and then update the crumb state with onItemPress:

```js
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import ButtonWithMenu from '../components/ButtonWithMenu';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import { ICON_SIZE } from '../Constants';

export default function Header({width,height,crumbNavigation,setCrumbNavigation}) {
  return (
    <View style={{flex:1,height, width}}>
      <View style={styles.navbar}>
        
        <ButtonWithMenu
          containerStyle={[styles.navbarButton,{marginLeft:ICON_SIZE}]}
          name="home"
          size={ICON_SIZE}
          color="black"
        />
        <ButtonWithMenu
          containerStyle={styles.navbarButton}
          name="close"
          size={ICON_SIZE}
          color="black"
          onItemPress={(sectionTitle, itemTitle) =>
            setCrumbNavigation((prev) => {
              const newCrumbNav = [prev[0]];
              if (sectionTitle) newCrumbNav.push(sectionTitle);
              if (itemTitle) newCrumbNav.push(itemTitle);
              return newCrumbNav;
            })
          }
          menu={[
            { title: 'Disconnect from Unit', data: [] },
            { title: 'Monitor Unit', data: ['This Thing', 'That Thing'] },
            { title: 'Unit Settings', data: ['This Thing', 'That Thing'] },
            {
              title: 'Unit Data Management',
              data: ['Stored Data Configuration', 'Stored Data Snapshot'],
            },
            { title: 'Information', data: ['This Thing', 'That Thing'] },
            { title: 'Help', data: ['This Thing', 'That Thing'] },
          ]}
        />
      </View>
      <LinearGradient
        colors={['#902337', '#21458d']}
        style={styles.colorBar}
        start={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
        locations={[0.5, 0.8]}
      />
      <View style={styles.crumbs}>
        <Text style={styles.crumbScreen} numberOfLines={1}>
          {crumbNavigation[0]} {crumbNavigation.length > 1 && ' > '}
          <Text style={styles.crumbTitle}>
            {crumbNavigation.slice(1).join(' : ')}
          </Text>
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  navbar: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  colorBar: {
    height: 5,
    width: '100%',
  },

  navbarButton: {
    // marginHorizontal: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: ICON_SIZE * 0.25,
  },
  crumbs: {
    overflow:'hidden',
    flexWrap:'none'
  },
  crumbScreen: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  crumbTitle: {
    color: '#21458d',
    fontWeight: '400',
  },
});
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/yVJxIsL2y)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer bro, this helps to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

For readability, I started by moving all of the components into their own separate files. I also used a FlatList instead of a ScrollView for the recursive SubMenuItem rendering.

I first broke the breadcrumb down into three components. The first, `MenuItem`, which would always be visible in the Header. When pressed, it would reveals a dropdown menu, which would reveal the `SubMenu`, MenuItem's children. Pressing `SubMenu` would reveal its children, if it had any, or would trigger navigation, if a routeName was provided. [Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/vjViXUCVm?platform=web)

Comment: I am working on making a `useCrumbItems` hook that will create the `arr` array so that it isnt as confusing working with it. If things go the way I think it will a navigation listener can be added to it so that the bread crumb can easily handle nested navigator navigation

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro, I would like to keep the menu visibility as toggle itself as like given in the snack demo in question. So in my application, if user clicks open menu (real app it will be hamburger menu icon), the menu opens with submenu and then the hamburger will be turned to close icon upon click on that the opened menu block will be closed. And this is the UX design provided by the design team.

Comment: But my query is only to make breadcrumb in each screen top left like, `Header 1 > Header 1 Submenu 1` , or `Header 2 > Submenu 2` etc.., based on the user navigated through the submenu's using menu dropdown.

Comment: I have edited the question with real app scenario and how the menu's and breadcrumb will look like for your reference bro.